# Safe navigating function for nested object properties

Tags: javascript

I've made a function to safely traverse deep objects.

```
var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: 1
    }
};

function getDeepProp(obj, properties) {

    if (typeof properties === 'string')
        properties = properties.split('.');

    if (typeof obj === 'undefined')
        return;

    if (!properties.length)
        return obj;

    return getDeepProp(obj[properties[0]], properties.slice(1));
}

console.log(getDeepProp(foo, 'bar.baz')); // 1
console.log(getDeepProp(foo, 'baz.baz')); // undefined

// The function was created to avoid exceptions like:
console.log(foo.baz.baz); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baz' of undefined
```

Please suggest possible improvements.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtkczasa/

Comment: I've let myself improving elclanrs code a little bit. See here for the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/5k7L973r/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a good exercise on recursion, but I'd suggest using built-in functions. Think that what you want to abstract is this syntax:

```
obj[a][b][c]
```

But doing some checking in between:

```
obj[a] && obj[a][b] && obj[a][b][c]
```

It seems to be a good job for a reducer, where `obj` is the accumulator, that gets passed along, and the properties are given as an array that you can reduce over, so `p` below will be each of the properties above:

```
function getDeepProp(obj, props) {
  return props.split('.').reduce(function(acc, p) {
    // if the accumulator is something
    // then lookup the next nested property
    // otherwise return undefined
    if (acc == null) return
    return acc[p]
  },obj) // the initial accumulator is the object
}
```

For example:

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1000
    }
  }
}

console.log(getDeepProp(obj, 'a.b.c')) //=> 1000
console.log(getDeepProp(obj, 'a.b.foo')) //=> undefined
```

Note that `acc` can be an object, or an array, since arrays are objects, and the bracket syntax is the same:

```
console.log(getDeepProp([[[2,[3]]]], '0.0.1.0')) //=> 3
```

Also, I would worry about the function doing too much. If properties have not been passed, then the function shouldn't be used in the first place. That's why I'd suggest, among other reasons, to take the object (the receiver of the operation), always last:

```
function getDeepProp(props, obj)
```

Comment: Nice, I would have never considered this.

Comment: I really like this solution. Great idea!

Comment: There's only one problem with this one. If `obj.a.b` is `null` (or simply "falsy", like `false`), then calling `getDeepProp(obj, 'a.b.c')` will also return `null` (or whatever the falsy value was), even though the `c` property has no right of existence (should be `undefined`). Voted up anyway, great and original approach :)

Comment: Or, if the `obj.a.b` is supposed to be a string and you'd use this function to check it's `length` property, then an empty string (`obj.a.b = ""`) will return the `""` and not the value of `length` (because an empty string is falsy in JavaScript).

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk, falsy values will work. Try `getDeepProp({a:{b:{c:false}}}, 'a.b.c')`, or with empty string, it should work.

Comment: @elclanrs, you didn't understand me apparently :) Create object like yours: `var x = {a:{b:{c:false}}}`. And now try this invocation: `getDeepProp(x, 'a.b.c.d')`. `d` has no right of existence, therefore function should return `undefined`. But it returns `false`.

Comment: @elclandrs, I've let myself improving your code a little bit. See this fiddle for the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/5k7L973r/

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk: Ah, I understand now. I edited the answer to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where `eval` is not actually evil, given some constraints.

```
function getDeepProp(properties) {
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$.]*$/.test(properties)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid property name: " + properties);
    }

    try {
        return eval(properties);
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Failed to get value for " + properties + " (" + error + ")");
    }
}

var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: "The value you want"
    }
};

console.log(getDeepProp("foo.bar.baz"));      // Logs the value of foo.bar.baz
console.log(getDeepProp("alert('Hacked!');"); // Throws an error
```

Modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtkczasa/1/

By using a Regular Expression, you guard against script injection attacks because only valid property names will be passed into `eval`, not arbitrary JavaScript commands.

In the context of accessing a property value, you must ask yourself this question: What's the difference between `foo.bar.baz`, `foo["bar"]["baz"]` (which is what your code essentially does), and `eval("foo.bar.baz")`?

Answer: There is no difference.

I haven't done a performance benchmark on our two approaches, but I'm thinking you'll get a slight performance boost using `eval` in this case.

People tend to blindly fear `eval` and this isn't necessary. The blog post [eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) made me rethink my fear of `eval` and I believe it has its place --- and this is one of them.

> Despite popular theory (and Crockford’s insistence), the mere presence of eval() does not indicate a problem. Using eval() does not automatically open you up to a Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack nor does it mean there is some lingering security vulnerability that you’re not aware of. Just like any tool, you need to know how to wield it correctly, but even if you use it incorrectly, the potential for damage is still fairly low and contained.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, though I have to admit that I don't like `eval`. If you look at this source https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js, you noticed that you need to adjust your regex

Comment: People often blindly fear `eval` without exploring the true risks. While the regex in my code won't allow `foo["bar"]`, I don't see that as a show stopper. It assumes the property you want to get is a valid property name in JavaScript.